# Google plugin for Eclipse: how to add JVM arguments in the Run configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-plugin-eclipse

I need to add arguments to my App Engine run configuration in Eclipse on the tab Arguments in the textbox Program Arguments, as mentioned in https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/developers-guide

```
 --jvm_flag=-Drdbms.server=local
 --jvm_flag=-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 --jvm_flag=-Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase?user=username&password=password
```

But I am always getting, quick error:

```
Usage: <dev-appserver> [options] <app directory>

Options:
 --help, -h                 Show this help message and exit.
 --server=SERVER            The server to use to determine the latest
  -s SERVER                   SDK version.
 --address=ADDRESS          The address of the interface on the local machine
  -a ADDRESS                  to bind to (or 0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
 --port=PORT                The port number to bind to on the local machine.
  -p PORT
 --sdk_root=DIR             Overrides where the SDK is located.
 --disable_update_check     Disable the check for newer SDK versions.
 --generated_dir=DIR        Set the directory where generated files are created.
 --jvm_flag=FLAG            Pass FLAG as a JVM argument. May be repeated to
                              supply multiple flags.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In `Run Configurations - Arguments`, add the following jvm_flag arguments to `VM arguments` section, not the `Program arguments` section:

```
-Drdbms.server=local
-Drdbms.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
-Drdbms.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourdatabase?user=username&password=password
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is wokring, but arguments that I have added are erased on the next time I run the configuration.

Comment: This could be a bug in Google Plugin for Eclipse, I have raised a issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=99&thanks=99&ts=1358638198).

Comment: Good. It looks like I am the only one in the world who is using it:-)